# Android int replaced with android.R.integer in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Probably a simple one but I can't seem to find out where to stop this. Each time I type in

```
int
```

it gets instantly replaced with

```
integer
```

and the package

```
import android.R.integer;
```

is automatically included.

Anyway of stopping this from happening in Eclipse?

Thanks

Comment: What version of JDK & Android SDK you are using ?

Comment: 1.7 JDK and 4.2 Android SDK (4.1.2 actually I think), not sure if this is relevant though?

Comment: ok, try changing JDK to 1.6 and see

Comment: eclipse version might be more related or do you have some custom code style setting?

Comment: Would it be a custom "Save Action" or "Content Assist" advanced or favorite setting?

Comment: also do you get "int" when you type "int" and press ctrl+space? I do. (and I don't have your problem)

Comment: It was my auto activation settings. I found a work around that works well for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had auto activation enabled with all characters enabled for activation triggers

.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

This was so I could get the auto suggestions for variables and function names but it was also causing int to turn into integer.

The only way around it is to give it a delay that is slower than how long it takes you to type 'int'. My delay was on 0 so I just set it to 100 and that works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you may try this:

> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Organize Imports -> **(check)** Do
>   not create imports for types starting with a lowercase letter

I'm not sure if it helps but lets give a try :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is already by default checked however.

Comment: did you earlier modify eclipse's preferences?

Answer (score 1):

The way I overcome this problem is by typing "int" and then hitting ESC.
I hope you will get the hang of it fast.

Comment: A good workaround that works. neither space nor square bracket stop it from auto completing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Integer** is class, **int** is a primitive type.

The Integer class wraps a value of the primitive type int in an object. An object of type Integer contains a single field whose type is int.

Comment: Acutally Integer <-- with a big I is the integer class, a small i is just wrong (We're talking android and java here)

Comment: I am aware of what they are. My question was how do I stop eclipse form automatically replacing 'int' with 'integer' when I type out those three letters.

Comment: @Warpzit *"Acutally Integer <-- with a big I is the integer class, a small i is just wrong"* - want to elaborate about that "just wrong" thing?

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com My eclipse at least won't eat: integer test = 7; but int test = 7; works fine. Do I need to elaborate in more detail?

Comment: @Warpzit actually android.R.integer is correct, It is provided in Standard Android API since version 3 , although it is not coherent with the java language naming conventions. see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.integer.html

Comment: @MuhammadAnnaqeeb your right but the original question was formulated different which is the reason for my answer.  As it stands now it's wrong but as so many have commented it I can't delete it :)